# Saving items to database w/ sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can someone please review my code? I'm saving a hotel rate to a database. I want to save the rate twice, one field will update with every new rate, and one field will contain the rate that was found for that date the first time it was captured.

The code looks very clunky and I know it can be improved.

```
def save_results(rates, session, hotel, govt):

    for item in rates:
        rate = Rate(**item)

        try:
            # check if already in database
            q = session.query(Rate).filter(Rate.hotel==hotel['object'], Rate.arrive==rate.arrive).first()

            # update inital_rate if that field is empty
            if q:
                if 'govt_rate' in item and q.govt_rate_initial is None:
                    q.govt_rate_initial = rate.govt_rate
                elif 'commercial_rate' in item and q.commercial_rate_initial is None:
                    q.commercial_rate_initial = rate.commercial_rate

            if q and govt is True:
                q.updated = datetime.utcnow()
                q.govt_rate = rate.govt_rate
            elif q and govt is False:
                q.updated = datetime.utcnow()
                q.commercial_rate = rate.commercial_rate
            else:
                if govt is True:
                    rate.govt_rate_initial = rate.govt_rate
                elif govt is False:
                    rate.commercial_rate_initial = rate.commercial_rate
                hotel['object'].rates.append(rate)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
```

Full code is below for reference. I would appreciate comments on any other portion as well!

```
# models
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    city = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    per_diem_rate = Column(Numeric(6, 2))

    hotels = relationship('Hotel', back_populates='location')


class Hotel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hotels'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    phone_number = Column(String(20))
    parking_fee = Column(String(10))
    location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('locations.id'), nullable=False)

    location = relationship('Location', back_populates='hotels')
    rates = relationship('Rate', back_populates='hotel', order_by='Rate.arrive', lazy='joined')


class Rate(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rates'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    govt_rate = Column(Numeric(6, 2))
    govt_rate_initial = Column(Numeric(6, 2))
    commercial_rate = Column(Numeric(6, 2))
    commercial_rate_initial = Column(Numeric(6, 2))
    arrive = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    govt_link = Column(String(500))
    commercial_link = Column(String(500))
    updated = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    hotel_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hotels.id'), nullable=False)

    hotel = relationship('Hotel', back_populates='rates')

def scrape_marriott(HOTELS_TO_SCRAPE):
        # create db session
        session = create_db_session()
        good = 0
        bad = 0

        # loop through list of hotels to scrape
        for item in HOTELS_TO_SCRAPE:
            try:
                # get or create a hotel linked to a location
                location = get_or_create(session, Location, city=item['city'])
                hotel = get_or_create(session, Hotel, name=item['name'], location=location)

                # create a hotel dictionary to pass to the other functions
                hotel = {'property_code': item['property_code'], 'object': hotel}

                # govt rates
                # get rates dictionary
                rates = get_rates(hotel, govt=True)

                # save to database
                save_results(rates, session, hotel, govt=True)
                time.sleep(randint(20, 30))

                # commercial rates
                # get rates dictionary
                rates = get_rates(hotel, govt=False)

                # save to database
                save_results(rates, session, hotel, govt=False)

                # log result and increase 'good process' counter
                print(item['name'] + ' processed successfully')
                good += 1

                # wait between 30 and 60 seconds before next loop
                time.sleep(randint(30, 60))
            except (AttributeError, TypeError, ConnectionError) as e:
                # log exception
                print('Error occured for ' + item['name'] + '. ' + e)
                email_message('Error occured for ' + item['name'] + '. ' + e)
                bad += 1
                continue
        print('{} processed, {} failed'.format(good, bad))
        email_message('{} processed, {} failed'.format(good, bad))
        session.close()


def get_rates(hotel, govt):
    dates = build_dates()
    rates = []

    # get rates for this month and next month
    for d in dates:
        soup = get_soup(d['arrive'], d['depart'], hotel, govt)
        rates += parse_rates(soup, govt)
        time.sleep(randint(2, 5))

    # remove duplicates
    filtered = []

    for i in range(0, len(rates)):
        if rates[i] not in rates[i + 1:]:
            filtered.append(rates[i])

    rates = filtered

    return rates


def get_soup(arrive, depart, hotel, govt):
    if govt is True:
        rateCode = 'GOV'
    else:
        rateCode = 'none'

    browser = RoboBrowser(parser='html.parser')
    browser.open('http://www.urlremoved?propertyCode=' + hotel['property_code'])

    time.sleep(1)

    form = browser.get_form(action='/reservation/availabilitySearch.mi?isSearch=false')

    form['fromDate'].value = arrive
    form['toDate'].value = depart
    form['flexibleDateSearch'] = 'true'
    form['clusterCode'] = rateCode

    # submit form
    browser.submit_form(form)

    return browser


def parse_rates(soup, govt):
    # get calendar links
    table = soup.find('table')
    urls = table.find_all('a', class_='t-no-decor')

    rates = []

    # loop through urls and parse each query string
    for item in urls:
        if len(item["class"]) == 1:
            # strip newlines and tabs
            raw_url = item['href'].replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace(' ', '')
            parsed_url = urlparse(raw_url)
            query = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)

            # convert date to datetime format
            res_date = query['fromDate'][0]
            res_date = datetime.strptime(res_date, '%m/%d/%y')

            if govt == True:
                # append data to rates list
                rates.append({
                    'arrive': res_date,
                    'govt_rate': query['rate'][0],
                    'govt_link': 'https://marriott.com' + urlunparse(parsed_url)
                })
            elif govt == False:
                # append data to rates list
                rates.append({
                    'arrive': res_date,
                    'commercial_rate': query['rate'][0],
                    'commercial_link': 'https://marriott.com' + urlunparse(parsed_url)
                })

    return rates


def save_results(rates, session, hotel, govt):

    for item in rates:
        rate = Rate(**item)

        try:
            # check if already in database
            q = session.query(Rate).filter(Rate.hotel==hotel['object'], Rate.arrive==rate.arrive).first()

            # update inital_rate if that field is empty
            if q:
                if 'govt_rate' in item and q.govt_rate_initial is None:
                    q.govt_rate_initial = rate.govt_rate
                elif 'commercial_rate' in item and q.commercial_rate_initial is None:
                    q.commercial_rate_initial = rate.commercial_rate

            if q and govt is True:
                q.updated = datetime.utcnow()
                q.govt_rate = rate.govt_rate
            elif q and govt is False:
                q.updated = datetime.utcnow()
                q.commercial_rate = rate.commercial_rate
            else:
                if govt is True:
                    rate.govt_rate_initial = rate.govt_rate
                elif govt is False:
                    rate.commercial_rate_initial = rate.commercial_rate
                hotel['object'].rates.append(rate)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the rest of the data structure, your `try` clause can be shortened:

```
    try:
        q = session.query(Rate).filter(Rate.hotel==hotel['object'], Rate.arrive==rate.arrive).first()

        if govt is True:
            sector = "govt"
        else:
            sector = "commercial"
        if q:
            if 'govt_rate' in item:
                sector = "govt"
            elif 'commercial_rate' in item:
                sector = "commercial"
            if q[sector + "_rate_initial"] is None:
                q[sector + "_rate_initial"] = rate[sector + "rate"]
        else:
            rate[sector + "_rate_initial"] = rate[sector + "_rate"]
            hotel['object'].rates.append(rate)
```

(This assumes you want the `govt` argument to `save_results` to be over-ridden by existing data in the field in cases where they don't match.)

Ideally, your fields should have a level for "sector". So instead of string concatenation as I've done, you would have:

```
q[sector].rate_initial = rate[sector].rate
```